# DeSerializing JSON string into a TS object

Tags: javascript, typescript, getjson

I am struggling over what should appear to be a very simple procedure.

In the "geolocate.ts" function "setData", the model indexes? "flightplan" and "config" are shown by Chrome debugger to be "undefined" when referenced from "model.flightplan" or "model.config". The "model" object itself seems to be fine even when expanded in the debugger.

Any thoughts or pointers would be very much appreciated ;)

**geolocate.d.ts**

```
export class FmsFlightPlan {
    public status: string[];
    ...
}

export class Config {
    public airportIcon: IconSettings;
    ...
}

export class InitModel {
    public config: Config;
    public flightplan: FmsFlightPlan;
}
```

**geolocate.ts**

```
import * as passedData from "./geoLocate.d";

let config: passedData.Config;
let flightPlan: passedData.FmsFlightPlan;

export function setModel( json: string): void {
    console.log( json);  // '{"Config": { "AirportIcon": {...} ...}, {"Flightplan": {"Status": [], ... } ...}'  --- As expected (JSONlint OK)

    const model: passedData.InitModel = JSON.parse( json);
    console.log(model);  // Chrome console: {Config: {…}, Flightplan: {…}}

    flightPlan = model.flightplan; // flightPlan and config are assigned "undefined"
    config = model.config;     // "model" looks OK and Intellisense works.

    flightplanDraw();
}
```

**TSC generated javascript**

```
function setModel(o) {
    console.log(o);
    var e = JSON.parse(o);
    console.log(e), flightPlan = e.flightplan, config = e.config, flightplanDraw()
}
```

**.NET Core View Javascript**

```
function gmapsReady() {

    initMap();
    $.getJSON("/Home/GetConfig",
        null,
        function(data) {
            setModel(data);
        });
 }
```

**.NET MVC Controller**

```
public JsonResult GetConfig()
{
    // Load fplan and config objects
    ...
    ... 

    InitModel initModel = new InitModel
    {
        Flightplan = fplan,
        Config = _config
    };

    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(initModel);
    return new JsonResult(json);
}
```

Comment: try 'flightPlan = model.Flightplan' and make sure the name is exactly the same including caps. JSON in JS is case sensitive (;

Comment: @ Helder De Baere: Many thanks for the suggestion, but using model.Flightplan results in a TSC compile error (as would be expected)

Comment: Then I'd suggest to rename 'flightplan' in your InitModel to 'Flightplan' and also for Config. If that doesn't work there's probably something wrong with the parsing of the JSON to your model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A first issue seems to be that you are accessing fields like `flightplan` and `config`, whereas in the JSON they are `FlightPlan` and `Config`. That's why you're getting `undefined`s.

A slightly bigger issue after that, which will mostly bite you if you plan on adding methods to your classes, is that the thing produced by `JSON.parse` is a simple JavaScript object, whereas `Config`, `FlightPlan` etc are classes, and instances of them would belong to that class. So if you had something like this:

```
let x = new Config();
x.airportIcon = 'foo';
console.log(x.constructor); // Prints 'Config'
let y = JSON.parse('{"airportIcon": "foo"}');
console.log(y.constructor); // Prints 'Object something or other'
```

So the two are structurally equivalent, but won't be functionally equivalent. Even by doing a TS cast you won't be able to call a function on `y` as you would on `x`. If these are simple DTOs than that's OK. But if not, you need to be explicit about this and do another step of translating from the JS object to your application ones.

---

Shameless plug: I wrote [raynor](https://github.com/horia141/raynor) to automate this exact process - of translating between a DTO type and a more useful JavaScript class.

---

You can also configure the JSON serializer on .net side to convert field names from `PascalCase` to 'camelCase`.

Comment: Thanks - I will investigate the naming issues for consisisteny. I have found names across C#/TS/JS "problamatic" since they all seem to have differing naming standards for public/private etc! - it sends my Resharper and Lints crazy !!! I am using "TypeScriptSyntaxPaste" to create d.ts files from C# classes, but will cvertainly give raynor a look.

Comment: Thank you. It was indeed a case issue during JSON serialization.  Using CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver "resolved" the issue.

These objects are (right now) simple DTOs , but I have bookmarked raynor for future reference. Thanks again.